# Processing csv file via pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my csv file contents

```
1.1.1.Top Header

Attribute,Field Description,Table,Column, Filter

Quarter,Fiscal Current Quarter,tableA,col1,A=B

Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah

Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah

Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah

1.1.2.Next Level

Attribute,Field Description,Table,Column, Filter

Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah
```

I am using python to extract the header information, column names such as  Attribute,Field Description,Table,Column, Filter
and finally the data. But is not working as intended.

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('dd.csv')

# Fill NaN values with "NA"
df = df.fillna("NA")

# Find the row indexes of the header rows
header_indexes = df[df.iloc[:,0].str.match(r'^(\d+\.)+\d+\..*')].index.tolist()

# Check if there are any headers and data rows
if header_indexes and header_indexes[-1] < len(df) - 1:
    # Extract header names and remove the numeric values
    header_names = [df.iloc[i,0].split('.')[1:] for i in header_indexes]
    header_names = [', '.join([h.strip() for h in header]) for header in header_names]
    
    # Extract the column names
    column_names = df.iloc[header_indexes[-1]+1,:].tolist()
    
    print("Header Names:", header_names)
    print("Column Names:", column_names)
else:
    print("No headers or data rows found in the CSV file.")
```

I want header Names as "Top Header", "Next Level"
Column Names as Attribute,Field Description,Table,Column, Filter

and finally the data.
Somehow, pandas is not able read the first line.

Comment: "Somehow, pandas is not able read the first line." How about df = pd.read_csv('dd.csv', names=[1,2,3,4,5]) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use Pandas directly for the detangling of the different parts. You could try something like the following instead (assumption is that you want the header names in a list and *all* of the data in one dataframe):

```py
import re
from io import StringIO

re_header = re.compile(r"^(?:\d+\.)+\d*(.*)$")
header_names, data_strings = [], []
with open("dd.csv", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if match := re_header.match(line):
            header_names.append(match.group(1))
            data_strings.append("")
        else:
            data_strings[-1] += line
dfs = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(string)) for string in data_strings)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).fillna("NA")
```

Result for the sample:

- `header_names`: `['Top Header', 'Next Level']`
- `df`:

  ```
     Attribute       Field Description   Table Column  Filter
  0   Quarter  Fiscal Current Quarter  tableA   col1     A=B
  1      Blah                    Blah    Blah   Blah    Blah
  2      Blah                    Blah    Blah   Blah    Blah
  3      Blah                    Blah    Blah   Blah    Blah
  4      Blah                    Blah    Blah   Blah    Blah
  ```

Answer (score 1):

"Somehow, pandas is not able read the first line."

You must assign a list of column names. if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are inferred from the first line of the file.

So you can try for example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dd.csv', names=[1,2,3,4,5])
```